# How to customize DateTime format for AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture

I currently have a Model class Product:

```
public class ProductModel
{ 
  public string? ProductName{ get; set; }
  public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using XUnit and AutoFixture for unit testing:

Below is my test method:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public async Task SaveProduct_ShouldSaveProductToDatabase(ProductModel productModel)
{
  var expiry = productModel.ExpiryDate; // 2020-03-17 03:01:27.2166623
  ... implementation to save to database
}
```

Autofixture is used to autogenerate the date and this is set to 2020-03-17 03:01:27.2166623. Is there a way to customize ProductModel to return a model property in a specific format. For instance I want date returned to be set as 2020-03-17 03:01:27 (Without milliseconds).

I have searched for examples and found one that retrieves specific dates:

```
public class AllProducts2020: ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<ProductModel>(composer =>
        composer.With(p => p.ExpiryDate, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)));
    }
}
```

The above actually returns all product where date year is 2020. I want to use the Custom class like above, except that I return all products with dateformat like this:2020-03-17 03:01:27 (Without milliseconds)

Any hint of how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with AutoFixture customization you can always try to create your own `DateTime` sequence generator (i.e. `ISpecimenBuilder`).

By default AutoFixture uses a random number generator to generate the total ticks value for the `DateTime` (see [RandomDateTimeSequenceGenerator](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/RandomDateTimeSequenceGenerator.cs)).
Since we know how many ticks there are in a second (`TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`). you can try to add/subtract the ticks delta, to round the value in the desired direction.

Once you're done with the specimen builder, customize your `Fixture` instance with it and you should have DateTime values rounded up to a second.